# Many threads, one method fails

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winapi, process

My application is System Tray Application, using C#, .NET 4.0.

I'm trying to display many PDF files at a time and each PDF should split screen with other window, that I determine by ProcessName, that's all.

The difficulty is that I need to wait until user closes that window (.WaitForExit() method), because later I'm deleting PDF file. And here problem comes.

In first thread everything goes fine but the problem is when i try to show second PDF file window processList[0] THOUGH MoveWindow function returns true, and handle to that window is also correct only pdf window is resizing, the other window fails.

In main method the only thread that I'm creating (I call this piece of code couple of times, everytime user want to see pdf file):

```
Thread pdfThread = new Thread(() => ShowPdfFile(fullPath));
pdfThread.Start();
```

Then (simplified code)

```
public static void ShowPdfFile(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                 Process pdfProcess = Process.Start(fileName);
                 Thread.Sleep(500);
                 string windowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
                 IntPtr pdfHandle = (IntPtr)FindWindow(null, windowTitle);
                 MoveWindow(pdfHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);

                 Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("someProcess");
                 MoveWindow(processList[0].MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);

                 pdfProcess.WaitForExit();
                 MoveWindow(processList[0].MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, max, max, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogToFile(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    LogToFile("Cannot delete file");
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE:** Well, I was debugging it whole day but just now i note that on second thread it doesn't wait on line pdfProcess.WaitForExit();
What should I change to force thread to wait for that exact pdfProcess exit?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem.

Comment: I think that's basically all. What more would you like to know?

Comment: I am unable to unserstand what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: When first thread launch it stops on pdfProcess.WaitForExit(); and wait there until every PDF will close. (it's almost good, i would like to wait only for that one exact PDF)
When second thread launch it DOESN'T stop on pdfProcess.WaitForExit(); and execute all lines, and just terminate itself i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel is right, however I found a solution! Here, maybe someone will use it.
Small comment: We must use winapi solutions instead of .WaitForExit().
The most important part is while loop, that waits for close pdf window.
Remember that FindWindow() and IsWindow() methods are from user32.dll (winapi).
This code run process based on it's paths, then gets it's handle and wait for it's closure.

```
Process pdfProcess = new Process();
pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
if (pdfProcess.Start())
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
    string windowTitle = string.Empty;

    foreach (Process process in processlist)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle) && process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(fileName))
        {
            windowTitle = process.MainWindowTitle;
        }
    }
    IntPtr pdfHandle = FindWindow(null, windowTitle);

    while (IsWindow(pdfHandle) && userExitedApp == false)
        Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic problem to your usage:
You start the external PDF application for each file. However this doesn't ensure that you have more than one process.

For example Acrobat reader only starts a single process. Additional files will just be "added" as new windows to the first process (You can check this by trying to manually open Acrobat reader twice --> won't work).

So in short: If you cannot control which PDF reader is used (and can ensure that you have a single process for EACH file) your approach will not work.

Note: Theoretically it would be possible to wait until the user closes the "reader window" that contains the specific file. However I strongly advise against this:

1. Looking up a window in a different process is very error prone (unless the process is explicitly designed in such a way...)
2. The solution would again depend on the reader application (you cannot be sure that Acrobat and Nitro use similar architecture to just name two readers)

Principally, if this feature is very important, you should consider to buy a PDF viewer component that allows to show the PDF's as windows of your own process.

**Edit**
The reason that the second thread isn't waiting is that the functionality to "add" a file to the first process uses a temporary process:

1. Temporary process is started for new file
2. Temporary process checks if the application is already running
3. Temporary process notifies the first process to open the specific file
4. Temporary process shuts down.

So waiting for that process will return almost immediately since the process in question already has stopped (or will stop in just a couple of milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads could utilize one method one after the other. Perhaps this video will help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhGXh9Z5GTw&feature=em-upload_owner

Comment: It's better to include efficient part of answer here, not just post external link. If this video will be deleted - youк answer will be useless.